# PrimeFaces Migration Issue - 5.1 to 5.2 : Component <p:selectOneRadio>

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

Following code is working with Primeface 5.1

```
<p:dataList value="#{dummyBean.formFieldBeans}"
    type="definition" var="xdata">
    <p:dataTable value="#{xdata.fields}" var="formPermConfigurator" >
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="#{xdata.fieldGroupName}" />
        </f:facet>
        <p:columnGroup type="header">
            <p:row>
                <p:column headerText="Field Name" />
                <p:column headerText="" />
                <p:column headerText="Deny" />
                <p:column headerText="Viewable" />
            </p:row>
        </p:columnGroup>
        <p:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{formPermConfigurator.fieldName}"
                title="#{formPermConfigurator.clientId}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <p:selectOneRadio id="customPermission"
                value="#{formPermConfigurator.permission}" layout="custom">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Deny" itemValue="Deny" />
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Viewable" itemValue="Viewable" />
            </p:selectOneRadio>
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <p:radioButton for="customPermission" itemIndex="0" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <p:radioButton for="customPermission" itemIndex="1" />
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</p:dataList>
```

But with Primeface 5.2, it is giving following error

```
j_idt99:j_idt120:1:j_idt122:0:customPermission: Validation Error: Value is not validj_idt99:j_idt120:1:j_idt122:0:customPermission: Validation Error: Value is not valid
j_idt99:j_idt120:1:j_idt122:1:customPermission: Validation Error: Value is not validj_idt99:j_idt120:1:j_idt122:1:customPermission: Validation Error: Value is not valid
```

p:selectOneRadio is used under p:dataTable (which in turn is used in p:dataList).

What I am changing in project is PrimeFaces version 5.1 to 5.2 in pom.xml

Server : jboss-as-7.1.1.Final

Comment: 1. What is the datatype of "formPermConfigurator.permission"? It should be String unless you defined a special JSFConverter...
2. Try to attach a debugger to the JBoss-AS and debug into the JSFConverter... I would guess that "Value is not valid" is connected to the converter.

Comment: @alfonx, formPermConfigurator.permission is String type.